# how to pass payload from Google sheet using Google Apps scripting?

Tags: google-apps-script

//Below is the code, I can pass this payload as hard-code value in code manually, but instead of this I need to fetch this value from Google sheet. Any suggestion please? // 
    /* Google Apps Script for Get company details By Id (NeoNova.AppDirect) */

```
function myFunctionpost() 

{
  var url = "http://............/html/get_company_details.php";

   var payload =
      {
        "companyId" : "748575e9-0eb7-44a5-84e9-96e568ca0f9c",
      };

  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "POST",
        "payload" : payload,   


      };

   var options = { "method":"POST","payload" : payload};

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'Company details By Id (NeoNova.AppDirect)';
  var body = Logger.getLog();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want something like [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

```
 // The code below will get the values for the range C2:G8
 // in the active spreadsheet.  Note that this will be a javascript array.
 var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getValues();
```

Or you can use the `getValue()` method which, according to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) which I suggest you give it a read:

> Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. The value may be
>   of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String depending on the value of the
>   cell. Empty cells will return an empty string.